# How do I show processes for a specific uid or username using command line in python?

Tags: python, process, command-line-arguments

```
for opt, arg in opts:
   if opt in ('-u'):
     arg = numuid
     ps = subprocess.Popen('ps -u ', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
     print ps.stdout.read()
```

this is what i have so far, numuid is supposed to go after ps -u and is the uid. but what do i do to have it read in whatever numuid is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the name as a variable, if you just want to see or store the output `check_output` is the simplest method:

```
from subprocess import check_output

out = check_output(["ps","-u", numuid])

print(out)
```

For python 2.6:

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen

p = Popen(["ps","-u", numuid], stdout=PIPE)
out, err= p.communicate()
print(out)
```

You don't need `shell=True` when you pass a list of args.

Comment: can you do something similar on python 2.6? I think check_output was introduced in 2.7

Comment: @shtuff. yes just use popen and communicate passing in the variable again